# Wired connection not working after update. Ethernet not listed in ifconfig

Tags: networking

I upgraded elementary OS to 0.3 and the wired connection is not working anymore. When I first installed elementary OS, I had to follow [these steps](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/). But I noticed that the ethernet is not even listed in ifconfig. I came across [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914065) but it seems old and I am not sure if it would apply for elementary OS.

Here are the output for the commands:

ifconfig -a

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:147573 (147.5 KB)  TX bytes:147573 (147.5 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:1c:a2:05:01:73  
          inet addr:192.168.29.242  Bcast:192.168.29.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a1c:a2ff:fe05:173/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3098 errors:0 dropped:478 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3117 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2462937 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:730402 (730.4 KB)
```

lshw -c NET

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe800fff memory:d0900000-d0903fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@8:1.3
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 68:1c:a2:05:01:73
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u ip=192.168.29.242 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: It seems that your system can detect your eth card. So i think your issue is anything about the config. What's your interfaces configuration? Try copy & paste from terminal: cat /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Here you go:
# interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: The reference to "network unclaimed" indicates that the driver is not loaded. Try in terminal with the command: modprobe r8168. Check your ethernet card.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved it by installing the driver for r8168.